# Selenium WebDriver Bot for Instagram

Tags: selenium, webdriver, instagram, bots

I am trying to develop a simple bot that likes instagram pictures from a special hashtag. I am using Selenium but I have problems with the action "click on picture". Login and searching hashtag works.
The xpath is right but when I run the program it doesnt find it.

```
public void like() {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='react-root']/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/a[1]/div[2]"))
                .click();

    }
```

Comment: Did you try your program on mock data from instagram just to rule out that it is not an API issue?

Comment: I am not using the API because I dont have the knowledge for that atm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the click function:

```
for (int second = 0;; second++) {
if (second >= 60) fail("timeout");
try { if (isElementPresent((By.xpath(".//*[@id='react-root']/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/a[1]/div[2]")))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
```